# Init Method of Class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, class

I'm not sure of the syntax for the init method of a class in objective c. I need to initialize a global object of a class that can be used in another class's methods. So MyClass1 object in MyClass2 that can be used in MyClass2's methods. If anyone knows the correct syntax for the init method and how to call it, I'd love to know. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I know this. I need to initialize a global object in a .m file that is also a class. The object has to be accessible to all the methods in that class.

Comment: Make `classOneInstance` an instance variable or better yet a property. Basically you have some reading and studying to do.

Comment: Every object is an instance of a class. I don't think you understand the terms well enough to explain your question. Perhaps if you give us the specific example of what you're trying to do we can help you better.

Comment: or, even better: OP could grab a book and could at least learn the very basics.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's what your Class2 interface file will look like:

```
//Class 2 interface
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//Forward declaration so we can keep the import private
@class Class1;

@interface Class2 : NSObject
@property Class1 *instanceVar;
@end
```

Now let's use your instance of Class1 in Class2's implementation:

```
#import "Class2.h"
#import "Class1.h"

//Now we can use our Class1 instance variable (property) below

@implementation Class2

-(void)funMethod {

    //Let's use instanceVar
    NSLog(@"%@", self.instanceVar);
}

-(void)coolMethod {
    //Let's use it again!
    NSLog(@"%@", self.instanceVar);
}

@end
```

Comment: besides it's name `globalVar` is just a normal property (with an implicit backing ivar). it has nothing to do with a global variable.

Comment: How is globalVar not considered a global variable, when it's an instance variable that can be accessed anywhere in the file?

Comment: I've been searching and all I can come up with difference wise when it comes to ivars/properties and globals is that a global variable is available to the entire app (all files), where as the property is only available where it's file has been imported?

Comment: I'm confused because since a property/ivar is considered global in scope throughout the entire file, then I thought it was considered a global variable, therefore properties, global variables, and instance variables are the same things correct?

Comment: a global variable indeed is a variable or object that is accessible from any part of an app. if it needs to be imported, doesn't matter. usually a global variable also exist form creation till app termination. if they are objects they might be called singletons. usage of global variables and singletons can indicate code smell. Variables that are accessible from within one class (classes can be distributed over several files), are called instance variables (ivars) as the exist in the scope of one instance of that class.

Comment: You just made my day. Thank you for taking the time to explain why I was wrong.

Comment: no, they are not the same things. global variables do exist app-wide, instance variables exist in one instance and properties might be handling getting and setting instance variables — but could also access other kind of data.

Comment: Note that `instanceVar` is only declared and never instantiated which was the crux of the question. so the two usages will just log null.

Comment: My real question is where do I initialize the object in the .m file so that its instance methods are accessible to that object globally in the .m file. I was informed that that should be done in the init method of the file the object is created in.

Answer (score 0):

How to initialize a class instance:

```
Class1 *classOneInstance = [[Class1 alloc] init];
```

Make sure you include the Class1 header file in the Class2 file.

Make classOneInstance an instance variable or better yet a property.

Basically you have some reading and studying to do.

Comment: You can also call `new` on the class as a convenience. This calls `alloc` and then `init`.